# Why $e^0=I$ for exponential operator?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

From definition of $e^T=\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{T^k}{k!}$, so $e^0=0^0$...

So, why $e^0=I$ for exponential operator?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, but the title and question allows for much broader answers, and it's also not so probable to associate that in that I'll find the answer for my question.

Comment: Not much broader, but just a special part from the duplicate, namely that $T^0=I$ for all matrices $T$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix exponential is **defined** by:

$$\exp(\boldsymbol{A}):= \boldsymbol{I}+\dfrac{1}{1!}\boldsymbol{A}+\dfrac{1}{2!}\boldsymbol{A}^2+\ldots$$

Set $\boldsymbol{A}=\boldsymbol{0}$ to get the result.

A way to understand what $0^0$ means or how we can define a useful value to this expression is to consider the definition: $$0^0:=\lim_{a\to 0}a^a=\lim_{a\to 0}\exp(a\ln a)=\exp(\lim_{a\to 0}a\ln a)=\exp(0)=1.$$

The limit $$\lim_{a\to 0}a\ln a=\lim_{a\to 0}\dfrac{\ln a}{\dfrac{1}{a}}$$

evaluate the last expression by using Bernoulli's limit law (aka L'Hospital's rule).

For a matrix we can also use a similar approach (assuming $\boldsymbol{A}$ is invertible):

$$\boldsymbol{I}=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}=\boldsymbol{A}^0.$$

---

An even more simple approach is to observe for $b\neq 0$:

$$1=\dfrac{b^a}{b^a}=b^0.$$

It makes sense to define $0^0:=1$ by the previous comment.

Comment: Actually, it starts with $\frac{A^0}{0!}$, and we set this to $I$ by definition.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: You are right, but writing $\boldsymbol{A}^0$ would again raise the question what $\boldsymbol{0}^0$ means :).

Comment: Many thanks  Mr. ;)

Comment: You treat $0$ as a number for $0^0$, but here we have matrices $T$. So we want that $T^0=I$, also for the zero matrix $T$.